# Backing a very large PostgreSQL DB "by parts"

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreQL DB that is about 6TB. I want to transfer this database to another server using for example pg_dumpall. The problem I have is that I only have a 1TB HD. How can I do to copy this database to the other new server that has enough space? Let's suppose I can not get another HD. Is there the possibility to do partial backup files, upload them to the new server, erase the HD and get another batch of backup files until the transfer is complete?

Comment: You dont need to store the backup on a file on disk. You can keep it inside the network stream (or: *pipe*). By using something like (from the destination side) `pg_backup -h source_host ... | pg_restore ...`

Comment: If you have a network connection between the two servers, you can simply run `pg_dump` **on the other server** so the file is stored there directly (ideally using the custom format using `-Fc`).

Comment: @wildplasser, sorry for my ignorance but are there pg_backup and pg_restore commands?

Comment: Oops, sorry. `pg_dump` is the name of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here(proof of concept):

- shell-command issued from the **receiving** side
- remote side dumps through the network-connection
- local side `psql` just accepts the commands from this connection
- the data is never stored in a physical file
- (for brevity, I only sent the table definitions, not the actual data: `--schema-only`)
- you could have some problems with users and tablespaces (these are global for an installation in Postgres) `pg_dumpall` will dump+restore these, too, IIRC.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

remote=10.224.60.103
dbname=myremotedbname

pg_dump -h ${remote} --schema-only -c -C ${dbname} | psql

#eof
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above if you have a fast network connection between source and destination you can do it without any extra disk.

However for a 6 TB DB (which includes indexes I assume) using the archive dump format (`-Fc`) could yield a database dump of less than 1 TB.

Regarding the "by parts" question: yes, it possible using the table pattern (`-t`, `--table`):

```
pg_dump -t TABLE_NAME ...
```

You can also exclude tables using `-T`, `--exclude-table`:

```
pg_dump -T TABLE_NAME ...
```

The above options (`-t` , `-T`) can be specified multiple times and can be even combined.
They also support patterns for specifying the tables:

```
pg_dump -t 'employee_*' ...
```